# how to call the button click event in post create dojo AMD module

Tags: javascript, dojo, toggle, amd

I created the new dojo application in dojo AMD module. I need to call the my button click in one script file to another script file. but when i clik the button its shows the null value error my sample code is given below:

My function file code is:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"  . . .], // defaultDuration
    function (declare . . ) { 


    var mycode = declare([ContentPane, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], { 

        toggle: function () {
        //here my function 
        },  
        constructor: function (params /) { 
        },

        postCreate: function () { 
        }
    });

    return mycode;
});
```

Button Click Event :

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare" . . . ],
    function (declare . . .) {

        var evet = declare([dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._TemplatedMixin], { 
            _div: null, 

            constructor: function (div) {
                this._div = div; 
            },

            postCreate: function () { 
                this.inherited(arguments);

                var markbutton = new Button({
                    label: "Mark", 
                }, this.markButtonNode); 

                markbutton.on("click", function (evt) {
                    this._div.toggle(); // error here _div is undefined. 
                });
            }
        });

        return evet;
    });
```

Comment: did u find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hitch the scope in order for `this` to work.

```
markbutton.on("click", lang.hitch(this, function (evt) {
    this._div.toggle(); 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can store scope in a variable and access this variable inside you function....

Try this:-

```
          var _this = this;
          markbutton.on("click", function (evt) {
                _this._div.toggle(); 
            });
```

In this approach, no need to require "dojo/_base/lang"...

Hope this will help you..